# Compare tables from local database to remote database

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the most efficient way to compare specific tables from one schema in local database with same tables on remote database? I would like to create something like view to see the tables, their counts and delta between them. What is the most efficient way to do this?

**Something like:**

```
Table (schema1) | Count | Table(schema2) | Count | Delta |
```

Comment: what about dumping both tables, then using diff utility like ```diff``` or ```kdiff``` or ```diffinity```?

Comment: @Kristian can you show example code or something as an answer?

Comment: check this link if works for you https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Comparing-two-tables-of-different-database-td2154070.html

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: @Henry perhaps you should add more details to your use case. It does smell like you're attempting to create a sort of data warehouse, which would open a few other questions ;) how dynamic are your data? depending on the update periodicity and data volume, using a foreign data wrapper would be the best choice. Otherwise a simple export/mport job triggered by pgagent would also be an elegant alternative